# Server-side image resizing performance

Tags: php, html

I have been noticing more and more from the big sites (Google, Facebook, Youtube and co) that they are resizing images "close" to their desired measurements client side and I am wondering whether this is a shift in the way people are thinking or them being lazy.

Take a scenario of adding a new image size to a standard set of images at particular sizes for a set of products (e-commerce) which number into the 100's of thousands, maybe millions.

Imagine I have a copy of my original image that is 300x350 or whatever and client side, resize it to 200x250. I do this for each product for 20 products on a page.

Is the work and problems server-side of accomodating this new size really worth the benefit client side?

If not then what is a good way to judge when you should pre-process a certain size?

If yes, is there ever a time where server-side processing and caching might become overkill (i.e. housing 8 images of 110x220, 120x230, 150x190 etc)?

Comment: Client side resizing is a godsend. My server chokes when a certain number of people upload pictures at the same time. This is the only way... Imagine the workload your CPU could save if most of the user uploaded pictures are half or fourth their original filesize. This can be done with canvas, resized and converted into a string before ingestion on the server side. It's good for the user experience, too, as it speeds up page load times. It's a win-win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to test this first on a single image on a page and did some multiplication math to anticipate multiple images. I should note:

- I was using pngs for this test however pngs seem pretty standard.
- I was using a particular function which apative resizes the image so that the `width` and `height` would always fit the original aspect ratio of the image I resized.

I got an image which was 450x450 (roughly) and decided to resize it down, client side, to 200x200 (all measurements in this answer are pixels). I found very little CPU jump by it despite the resize being more than half of the images total size.

The quality was also good across all modern browsers, Chrome, Opera, Firefox and IE all showed the image as clear as if it was done in Photoshop or GD.

On on IE7 I didn't notice much of a CPU jump and the quality was good provided I used a percentile resize based upon the images size constraints.

Overall the additional storage, computation and coding required to make even this size cache server side seemed to be at a disadvantage to the power that can be implied on the user end.

That being said, if I were to start doing multiples of this type of resizing (say 20, as in my question) I would probably start to hit problems.

After some tweaking around I found that anything under 1/3 of the original images size, provided the image was under 1000px in width or height, seemed to be negliable to CPU and general computer performance.

With the added function I was using I got just as good quality from resizing client side as I did server side. The specific function I used (for interested parties) was:

```
function pseudoResize($maxWidth = 0, $maxHeight = 0){

$width = $this->org_width;
$height = $this->org_height;

$maxWidth = intval($maxWidth);
$maxHeight = intval($maxHeight);

$newWidth = $width;
$newHeight = $height;

// Ripped from the phpthumb library in GdThumb.php under the resize() function
if ($maxWidth > 0)
{
    $newWidthPercentage = (100 * $maxWidth) / $width;
    $newHeight          = ($height * $newWidthPercentage) / 100;

    $newWidth = intval($maxWidth);
    $newHeight = intval($newHeight);

    if ($maxHeight > 0 && $newHeight > $maxHeight)
    {
        $newHeightPercentage    = (100 * $maxHeight) / $newHeight;

        $newWidth = intval(($newWidth * $newHeightPercentage) / 100);
        $newHeight = ceil($maxHeight);
    }
}

if ($maxHeight > 0)
{
    $newHeightPercentage    = (100 * $maxHeight) / $height;
    $newWidth               = ($width * $newHeightPercentage) / 100;

    $newWidth = ceil($newWidth);
    $newHeight = ceil($maxHeight);

    if ($maxWidth > 0 && $newWidth > $maxWidth)
    {
        $newWidthPercentage = (100 * $maxWidth) / $newWidth;

        $newHeight = intval(($newHeight * $newWidthPercentage) / 100);
        $newWidth = intval($maxWidth);
    }
}

return array(
    'width' => $newWidth,
    'height' => $newHeight
);
}
```

So it does seem from my own testing that housing every size of every image your going to use, i.e. as I asked in my question:

> If yes, is there ever a time where server-side processing and caching might become overkill (i.e. housing 8 images of 110x220, 120x230, 150x190 etc)?

Does seem to be overkill in modern computing and rather you should go for close measurements if you intend to use many different size of many images.

I have found, however, that if you have a standard set of sizes and they are small then the advantage is actually to server side resize and storage of all sizes since forcing the client to resize will always slow their computer down a little but scaling under 1/3 of it's original size seems to not make too much of a difference.

So I believe that the reason why sites such as FB and Google and Youtube don't worry too much about storing exact measurements of all their images is because "close-to-measurement" scaling can be more performant overall.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following:
Image resizing is heavy process for server. It first of all costly itself. Secondly it is harddrive IO operations which ARE quite slow. SO it all depends on how loaded your server is.

For client it matters in two ways:

1) Thumbnails are smaller in file size and hence are much faster to download. SO they will appear way faster. But that all depends on speed of Internet connection, which day by day is increasing. Have you seen how large images are loaded? They will not be displayed whole at once, but rather by 'lines'

2) If you try to display large image in small size, the quality will be much much much lower. It is because of how browsers process it. They do not have capabilities of Photoshop and cannot do proper quality resizing.

3) Many large images on single page will increase memory usage by that page. On some not so powerful computers that may give terrible lags while scrolling opening it.

As  a solution to this question i more tend to do what i have seen in one of Drupal modules (`imagecache` if i am right).

It does not create thumbnails on image upload. Instead it creates them on request time using .htaccess and mod_rewrite capabilities. It checks if requested file does not exist and if no it redirects request to small and light-weight PHP script which will create the thumbnail, write it to filesystem and then output to client.

So next visitor will already get previously created thumbnail.

Thus you implement postponed/lazy image resizing, which will make the load smoother (stretch it in time).

Comment: 1) The dimensions are 100px in difference as such as can count the download size as being 10kb in difference for a fully optimised png. 2) that resize is 100px and also server-side it would use gdlibrary not photoshop, plus photoshop adds a huge amount of bloat to a file causing a huge download need. I mean I can't photoshop all 200K product images. 3) I wouldn't mind knowing the details of memory usage though.

Comment: @Sammaye also when i worked for e-commerce company, we used Javascript which will postpone loading of image until they are actually displayed. So if image was out of screen (you'd need to scroll down to see it) then it was not loaded at first and then once you actually scroll to it it will be loaded.

Comment: Yea the gradual loading is something I do wanna do some day however this site is quite ancient and an addon like that would not fit well atm.

Comment: @Sammaye i used photoshop as a comparison of browser image render capabilities. Of course if you resize them using gd library, the quality also will be not as good photoshop. BUT it will be way better quality comparing to how browser would render it. regarding 2 and 3 you could try to do some experiments yourself and see the outcome. And then decide. There are tons of techniques you could speed up your page, how improve image quality etc.

Comment: @Sammaye, well, what can i do here? I gave you basic reasons, but everyone must decide himself what way he/she should go. What we did in the end (bcz traffic was too high) is to apply all of ways we could improve it. SO lets say we have original image 800x600. Then on page we use 150x100, 200x250, 400x300 and original size. So we had to create only two thumbs. 200x250 and 400x300 and then use 200x250 for 150x100 as well. This is one way, but there are lots of them if you think carefully.

Comment: When you say "200x250 for 150x100 as well" do you mean you processed the resize client side?

Comment: @Sammaye not really process it, but allow browser render 250x200 in `<img width="150" height="100">`. Yes it will be not very good quality. But it is small enough for quality not to matter that much. (Of course i meant not 200x250, but 250x200)

Comment: You asked for `good way to judge`, i gave you a few techniques you can use and reasoning why you use this or that. All other is just a logical thinking depending on your specific conditions. Each separate case would require its own approach which you always can figure out yourself.

Comment: Well I mean your answer lacks certain things like, I know ff uses opengl for 3d and 2d rendering, now that is what photoshop mostly uses as well so actually the quality from both are good. download size, as proven by above comments, are too small to care really and I have no idea what you mean by memory usage since that will occur even if you server-side scale images since the images have to be held in memory on the client computer when rendered (maybe you meant CPU there?). Also the question wasn't really answered well imo. So the answer just doesn't feel very authoritative.

Comment: But then how much CPU would be needed for a render of 100px(2) compared to 1000px(2) (of course the first thing is the amount of computes per second required but yea)? That is one of the points I am looking for, is someone who knows that, who has experience in image scaling through this manner.

Comment: 1) it is still memory usage. in the way that these images are stored in memory. when you scroll page it is being re-rendered. So in case of large images it will have to quickly(!) process many large blocks of memory. which will depends on bus speed. it will not produce high CPU or GPU usage, bcz algorithms for it are quite simple. But operating large blocks of memory is still pretty much a bottleneck in computer speed.

Comment: how much CPU? In what units? in flops? that won't tell you generally anything. In percents? On what CPU then? Which server do you use? Is it dedicated server with real HW or is it cloud server with emulated HW? Do you feel it? You need to figure it out depending on your current situation. None will be able to tell you that.

Comment: However -- never mind. I explained pretty much a lot of things here, which easily can be found on tons of articles on web. But still people instead of googling decide post question to SO. Which is quite awkward. I normally ask questions only after hours of trying to find answer either myself or given by others, but lately people just want to be served for free.

Comment: I still don't get your first comment, I wasn't asking about memory usage of a lot of images on a page. In terms of CPU I wanna know: would 100px(2) post-processed scaling of an image be so detrimental to a PC performance so I shouldn't do it? I mean other big sites such as FB and Youtube and Google do it. So I wanna know whether the status quo of scaling all images, for every size you need, server side and caching them is better than doing a hybrid solution of keeping a standard set and client scaling close measurements.

Comment: i already said it 3 times. You need to choose according to your situation. If you need to process new images constantly (means 24/7 and say 10 images/sec), then you really need to consider that, however if you have an e-commerce site, where you process at most 20-30 new images per day, just forget about it and do pre-process them to as many thumbnails as you want. Each single image with no super large dimensions (imo super large > 3000px*2000px) processed will take it less than 0.2-0.5 second on even old hardware and still will leave enough CPU and memory for other requests.

Comment: Also why i am always talking about memory? Because PHP weakness is memory and not CPU. If it takes too much CPU it will just be slow and cause that client will have to wait half-sec more, but overlimiting memory will cause crash of that process and result in no answer to client at all. Cheers.

Comment: I talk about CPU because the memory of PHP is easily solvable with some nifty programming. The problem is the amount of weight a image recalculation puts on a CPU, much like video encoding, my distributed video encoder only uses 100meg RAM at any given time but uses 8 cores of a CPU at all times, yea ok it's a bit of a stretch but you get the idea. Also that's the first time you can said it properly in full, other times it was hard and confusing you follow you fully, though because of misleading facts in the answer now I am gonna go off and find out the knowledge an easier way (ironically).

Comment: The problem, even though done through PHP is not on the PHPs end, it is on the clients end, in their browser. I can resize 1000 images a min in PHP on commodity hardware atm, that is no problem to me, the problem is of getting the client to do the CPU work. Your last comment kind of answers that but your answer has been so misleading til now I am gonna find the knowledge another way.

Comment: You cannot even compare video encoding and image resizing. Video encoding is way more costly in both CPU and RAM usage, however image processing is way simplier. It is still heavy process when it comes to high-load projects. But if (as you say) it is just an e-commerce site, then just do pre-processing. If it is less than 5m hits a day, then it is not high-load.

Comment: But if it so low traffic would it not be more expensive to house many multiples of images than let the client scale to closest? I mean this is part of my question: "If yes, is there ever a time where server-side processing and caching might become overkill (i.e. housing 8 images of 110x220, 120x230, 150x190 etc)?" so in this case would you still stand with "200x250 and 400x300 and then use 200x250 for 150x100 as well." over all pre-processing? But you would say that under a high load scenario a hybrid should be used?

Comment: for really high-load -- separate server with static preprocessed files; for average load (5m-10m hits/day) -- hybrid. Less than 5m hits/day any you like. But just a hint (from personal experience) -- do not put all files in same folders. Too many file nodes in one folder will cause long file name resolving (as IO operation), hence it will make any operation with image files freaking slow. Faced it when came to one of projects where >1m image files were in same folder and they were surprised what site opening so slow.

Comment: That's interesting because, ofc, a CDN bucket is effectively a replicated folder and a CDN bucket can become massive. But yea I didn't know that about the IO op of the file name look up, I always thought that so long as all files were in one folder it lowered the lookup cost to a bare min.

Comment: @AlexKey Do not ask people to accept your answer, it is purely at the choice of the person asking the question.  Comments asking for marks are noise and will be deleted.